# Read GeoTiff from memory in GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, c++, hadoop

Is it possible with the `GDAL` library to read an image (e.g. GeoTiff) from a memory stream, like `stdin` instead of a defined location on the local disk?

It would be useful to read data in streaming environments. In my case I would like to use the Hadoop Streaming API, which reads the datastream from HDFS, so passing a file URI to the `GDALOpen()` function is not possible.

Comment: Is this anything to that direction http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Create-gdaldataset-from-in-memory-Image-Bitmap-byte-MemoryStream-td3749112.html? Found from the web with search "gdal memory stream".

Comment: Thanks, I skipped this one, because it started with C# bindings. But it really answers my question, there is a `VSIFileFromMemBuffer` C/C++ function to read a stream into a virtual file and retrieve a path starting with "/vsimem/". The problem was that I looked for a solution to pass the memory stream to `GDALDataSet` or `GDALOpen` and not to get a virtual path for the data :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var geoJsonToBeCaclBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(geometry));
string geoJsonToBeCaclFileName = $"/vsimem/{Guid.NewGuid()}.geo.json";
Gdal.AllRegister();
Gdal.FileFromMemBuffer(geoJsonToBeCaclFileName, geoJsonToBeCaclBytes);
```

maybe load these memory stream into `/vsimem` file path, then use gdal api read these file through this path.

see also : https://www.gdal.org/gdal_virtual_file_systems.html#gdal_virtual_file_systems_vsihdfs